# Why has Visual Studio's Windows Forms Designer stopped working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I'm in the process of cleaning up an old bit of C++-CLI software by decoupling business logic from the GUI. Despite the fact that I've left the windows forms designer code well alone, it now won't display my form and instead, throws an exception:

```
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

The call stack looks like this:

```
at EnvDTE.CodeFunction.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart Part)
at Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

...none of which is my code. What might I have disturbed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the call stack it looks like the WinForms designer is choking trying to read the code inside the `InitializeComponents` method in the generated file.  The actual faulting party is the C++ code model implementation.

What's most likely happening here is a particular statement in the method is causing the code model to error here.  I would start by commenting out the entire method, verifying that fixes the problem and then slowly uncommenting sections until I tracked down the offending line

Comment: Well I'm not sure what it was, because I've not changed a sausage, but it appears to have suddenly come back to life. If it happens again, I'll have a look at your suggestions. Cheers anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is none of your own code in `InitializeComponent()` function.I replaced it and it works normally now)

Answer (score -1):

i googled the error and there were a few threads citing various different applications that all produce this error:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1148764.aspx/1
and 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/11e91d76-f5f3-45c3-b3f6-30c1e4121b9f/

being just two

the chief cause of this error seems to be a user or process attempting to access, run or write to something it does not have access to.

Have you tried running the application as an administrator?

if that doesn't work make sure both the project folder and the application folder are on the same partition as that can affect permissions.

you have not upgraded your OS since that application was installed by any chance? If so your GUID may not match the stored GUID on the Application and that could be causing the error uninstalling/re-installing will fix this.

hope that helps

Comment: This has nothing to do with running the application (which works just fine); it's just windows forms designer that's falling over while I try to alter the GUI.